# Computer Networks, bandwidth calculation

Tags: computer-networks

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this kind of questions, but I'm a little desperate and I can't find the answer to this Computer Networks exam question.

*"A point to point 1000 km connection uses a Idle RQ frame protocol with a frame of 1 KByte. Calculate the bandwidth to use at its maximum the line. Is it possible to increment the bandwidth by incrementing the frame size? Why?"*

I've tried to reverse the formula for the efficiency calculation by putting U = 1 but it seems to be impossible because the last step turns out to be bw = 0

I also tried to relate the frame size and the bandwidth but that's something used for the CSMA/CD which is not involved in this excercise

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It looks like your question fits this site.

Comment: "I've tried to reverse the formula for the efficiency calculation by putting U = 1 but it seems to be impossible because the last step turns out to be bw = 0". Can you show your calculation **in detail**? Once you have done that, people will be able to help much faster and better.